# OnDelete errors or shadow properties created when trying to add a link between two models in EF Core 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I know there are many similar questions about these issues, but I've spent the past few hours reading them, and haven't found a solution to my problem, so please be patient with me!

My use case is that distributors rent devices from us. The distributors then rent these devices out to organisations who use them.

I'm part-way through building the models, and have the following so far (irrelevant properties removed for clarity)...

```cs
public class Device {
  public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
  public string SerialNumber { get; set; } = "";
  public List<DistributorRental> DistributorRentals { get; set; } = new();
  public List<OrganisationRental> OrganisationRentals { get; set; } = new();
}

public class DistributorRental {
  // Represents when a distributor rents a device from us
  public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
  public string DeviceId { get; set; } = "";
  public Device Device { get; set; } = new();
  public string DistributorId { get; set; } = "";
  public virtual Distributor Distributor { get; set; } = null!;
  public DateTime Start { get; set; }
  public DateTime? End { get; set; }
}

public class OrganisationRental {
  // Represents when an organisation rents a device from a distributor
  public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
  public string DeviceId { get; set; } = "";
  public Device Device { get; set; } = new();
  public string OrganisationId { get; set; } = "";
  public Organisation Organisation { get; set; } = null!;
  public DistributorRental DistributorRental { get; set; } = null!;
  public DateTime Start { get; set; }
  public DateTime? End { get; set; }
}
```

I haven't shown the `Distributor` or `Organisation` models as I don't think they are relevant, but you can see them in the database diagram below, which shows the result of the above...

[image: Database diagram of what I have so far]

Now, I also need a link from the `OrganisationRental` to the `DistributorRental`, as an organisation can only rent a device from a distributor if that distributor has a rental from us.

I added the following to the `OrganisationRental`...

```cs
public DistributorRental DistributorRental { get; set; } = null!;
```

...and the following to the `DistributorRental`...

```cs
public ObservableCollection<OrganisationRental> OrganisationRentals { get; set; } = new();
```

The migration was added fine, but when I tried to update the database, I got the following error...

*Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_OrganisationRentals_DistributorRentals_DistributorRentalId' on table 'OrganisationRentals' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints*

OK, so I need to specify the delete behaviour. I removed the migration and added the following to my context...

```cs
builder.Entity<DistributorRental>()
  .HasMany<OrganisationRental>()
  .WithOne(or => or.DistributorRental)
  .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

However, when I try to add the migration, I now get two warnings...

*There are multiple relationships between 'OrganisationRental' and 'DistributorRental' without configured foreign key properties. This will cause Entity Framework to create shadow properties on 'OrganisationRental' with names dependent on the discovery order*

...as well as...

*Both relationships between 'DistributorRental.Device' and 'Device' and between 'DistributorRental' and 'Device.DistributorRentals' could use {'DeviceId'} as the foreign key. To resolve this, configure the foreign key properties explicitly in 'OnModelCreating' on at least one of the relationships*

I have tried adding all sorts of things to the context to try and solve this, but keep getting shadow properties. For example, I tried this...

```cs
builder.Entity<Device>()
  .HasMany<DistributorRental>()
  .WithOne(dr => dr.Device)
  .HasForeignKey(dr => dr.DeviceId)
  .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

builder.Entity<Device>()
  .HasMany<OrganisationRental>()
  .WithOne(or => or.Device)
  .HasForeignKey(or => or.DeviceId)
  .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

Can anyone explain what is going wrong and how I sort it out? I've spent hours going round in circles, and really don't understand what EF is doing.

Thanks